# Nameless functions in Typescript?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

In knockout-2.2.d.ts we have:

```
interface KnockoutObservableAny extends KnockoutObservableBase {

    (): any;
    (value): void;
}
```

I understand that (): is used to declare a function with an empty parameter list and a return type after the colon.

However I don't understand the lack of a function identifier in front of the brackets.

I would have expected something like functionName(): any;

What does this "anonymous" function mean? How do I interpret this nameless function, thanks.

Comment: it is an interface definition... I'm thinking that maybe it should be interpreted as: classes that implement this interface should have at least 1 function that takes no parameters that returns a variable of type "any" and that the class should also have a function which takes "value" as a parameter and returns nothing (void)

Answer (score 2):

The following interface describes a function that acts like a property getter, a common pattern in the JavaScript world:

```
interface Property {

     //getter
     (): string; 
}

//assume p: Property;
var value = p();  //The type of value will be a string.
```

As it is, the interface is equivalent to this functional type:

```
() => string
```

The difference is that in the first example, you can describe a function that has properties and additional overloads:

```
interface Property {
     //getter
     (): string; 

     //setter
     (value: string): void;

     //register for the change event.
     onPropertyChanged(handler: (newValue: string) => void): void;
}

//assume p: Property
var value = p();
p.onPropertyChanged(newValue => { value = newValue; })
p('newValue');  //Would set the value variable to 'newValue'
```

Knockout uses binding properties that follow this pattern, and the syntax described here and used in your example allows for this type of pattern to be defined in TypeScript.

As for the function being nameless, well you are declaring an interface. Each function that satisfies the interface would have a different name.

Personally, I would have found the syntax clearer if it followed the pattern used in C# for indexers:

```
//WARNING: Not valid TypeScript
interface Property {
     //getter
     this(): string; 

     //setter
     this(value: string): void;

     //register for the change event.
     onPropertyChanged(handler: (newValue: string) => void): void;
}
```

In my opinion, this syntax makes it clearer that the function declaration describes the object implementing the interface, and not one of its methods.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as call signatures. All `interfaces` have no runtime code generation associated. They simply exist to help the compiler do type checking. E.g.

```
interface Foo{
    ():number; // when you call it it returns a number
    (message:string):string; // when you call with a message it returns a string 
}

var foo:Foo; 

var num = foo();
var str = foo('Hello world!');
```

Comment: This helps but I'm still confused...I thought that all functions in an interface must be defined in the class the implements the interface.

Comment: Not all `interfaces` can be implemented by a `class` in typescript. Reason is that interfaces are used to describe valid behaviour for JavaScript (not just typescript classes). In JS you can do stuff like `function foo(){}; foo.bar=funciton(){}` where a function has member which is a function etc which it not really good *`class`* design

Comment: Ok that helps- also I noticed that in (value): void; there is no type specified for "value", does this mean that specifying the type of a parameter is optional in Typescript?

Comment: Specifying the type is optional in all cases in typescript. Not just parameters but also return, variables etc. if you don't specify the type it is assumed to be *any*

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```js
interface SiblingMethods {
  [key: string]: (param: number) => string;
}

const methods: SiblingMethods = {
  dynamicInterface1(paramFor1: number) {
    return "dynamicInterface1";
  },

  dynamicInterface2(paramFor2: number) {
    return "dynamicInterface2";
  },
};
```

---

I was looking to create an interface that would allow any property name, but the property had to be a function that only accepted specific params and returned a specific type.

Wasn't really sure what to google but ended up getting it after actually thinking for a second instead.

```js
interface ChannelMethods {
  [key: string]: (methods: ActionCable.CreateMixin, params?: any) => ActionCable.Channel;
}
```

This would allow a function to return an object of functions whose names don't matter but the params and return types have to be adhered to.

```js
let cable: ActionCable.Cable;

export const ChannelFp = function(methods: ChannelMethods): ChannelMethods {
  if (!cable) cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(WEBSOCKET_HOST);
  return methods;
}

const PatientChannelFpMethods: ChannelMethods = {
  appointmentChannel(methods: ActionCable.CreateMixin, appointmentId: string) {
    return cable.subscriptions.create({
      channel: 'Patient::AppointmentChannel',
      appointment_id: appointmentId,
    }, methods);
  },
}

export const PatientChannelFp = function(): typeof PatientChannelFpMethods {
  return ChannelFp(PatientChannelFpMethods) as typeof PatientChannelFpMethods;
}
```